# How to look up the style inheritance for an object in Flex? 

Tags: apache-flex, styles, flex4, flex-spark

I would like to know what CSS styles are affecting my UIComponent and from where.

So the solution would list the styles and values of the given component:

```
<s:Label id="myLabel" />

<s:Group id="myLabel" fontFamily="Tahoma"/>
    <s:Label id="myOtherLabel" />
</s:Group>
```

Then the code:

```
var styles:Object = StyleManager.getStyles(myLabel);
trace(styles);
```

fontFamily - Arial
color - 0
fontSize - 12
textAlign - left
etc

And then I could find out where style is getting it's value from:

```
var styleParent:Object = StyleManager.getStyle(myLabel, "fontFamily");
trace(styleParent); // "s|Label" declaration or global?
```

And the style look up:

```
var styleParents:Array = StyleManager.getStyleInheritence(myOtherLabel, "fontFamily");
trace(styleParent); // inline which overrides "s|Group fontFamily" which overrides "s|Label" which overrides global
```

When I say overrides I mean the specificity. Inline fontFamily declaration is more specific than inline fontFamily declaration on the label parent group which is more specific than the s|Label type declaration which is more specific than the global fontFamily declaration.

This image gives you an idea of how Firebug gives you style info on the selected object:

[image]

**For example:**

```
var myInheritenceChain:Array = getStylesInheritanceForTarget(myButton);

trace(myInheritanceChain); // output is an array of 

[0] {subject:instance, type:inline, styles: {fontFamily:"Noteworthy", color:"blue"}
[1] {subject:spark.components.Button, type:type, styles: {fontFamily:"Bidoni", color:"red"...}
[2] {subject:#myButton, type:id, styles: {fontFamily:"Futura", color:"green"}
[3] {subject:.myClassStyle, type:class, styles: {fontFamily:"Times New Roman", color:"yellow"...}
[4] {subject:global, type:something, styles: {fontFamily:"Helvetica", color:"black"...}
[5] {subject:*, type:something, styles: {fontFamily:"Bauhaus", color:"black"...}
```

So that you can see why and how the style, for example, fontFamily, is set to the value it's set to like so:

```
var myInheritenceChain:Array = getStylesInheritanceForTarget(myButton, "fontFamily");
```

Comment: I've never tried to know all style inheritance at running time, but surely there's a way to do it. Anyways, I recommend you to read Adobe Flex 4.6 Help documentation: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7e83.html.

There, it explains how inheritance is applied and how it supposed to work.

This can give you a clue to implement something that suits your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `package mx.styles`. Copy to this package files StyleProtoChain, CSSStyleDeclaration, CSSMergedStyleDeclaration and implement functionality what you need in this classes.

For example you can override

```
override mx_internal function addStyleToProtoChain(chain:Object,
                                          target:DisplayObject,
                                          filterMap:Object = null):Object
{
    // If we have a local style, then add only it to the chain. It will
    // take are of adding its parent to the chain.
    // If then is no style, but a parentStyle, then add the parent Style
    // to the chain.
    if (style)
        return style.addStyleToProtoChain(chain, target, filterMap);
    else if (parentStyle)
        return parentStyle.addStyleToProtoChain(chain, target, filterMap);
    else
        return chain;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what to do with this. I was looking for some code that creates and object that shows me something like this (posted above).

Answer (score 0):

you can debug a component’s inheriting styles by using the static ObjectUtil.toString() method to display a component’s inheritingStyles property.

demo: 
http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/12/24/displaying-a-combobox-controls-inherited-styles-in-flex/

```
<mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;

            private function init():void {
                textArea.text = ObjectUtil.toString(comboBox.inheritingStyles);
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
```

Comment: That shows the styles and values that this object has but not how to look up the style inheritance (where the values are coming from or owned by).